# Shared HTTP Servers not processing if response is not written into

Tags: dart, httpserver

I have this code:

```
void handle(HttpRequest request) async {
  request.response.write('Hello');
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  request.response.close();
}

void main() {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8080);
  server.listen(handle);
}
```

And that works properly, all the requests are processed in the same time, now I'm wondering why if I move the `response.write` after the `Future`, it can only processes only one request at time.

I can reproduce this only in Chromium browser, in Internet Explorer, Edge or CURL requests this doesn't happen.

```
void handle(HttpRequest request) async {
  print('Request on ${Isolate.current.hashCode}');
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  request.response.write('Hello');
  request.response.close();
}
```

Any info if there is a fix(leaving the `response.write` after the Future) or any explanation about why this is happening is welcome.

Comment: Can you give some information of how your test works? I cannot reproduce the problem you have with running 5 instances of curl at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I've ran more tests and I cannot reproduce it using curl, or any browser but chrome. For example if I open chrome with 2 tabs and load the page in both tabs, (running the server with the code from the first example) it takes for both tabs a total of 5 seconds, whereas if I use the code from the second example, to load both tabs it takes 10 seconds, 5 for the first tab, and (then) 5 for the second one (I guess that they aren't loaded concurrently and this is a Chrome issue).

Comment: This has nothing todo with isolates then, I've tidied to code.

Comment: Well, I can only guess but I think the reason for the behavior in Chrome is because the browser does have a max number of connection which it tries to open at the same time. So in your first example, you immediately sends the first byte back to the browser which trigger the browser to start open more connections. In your second example, your are waiting 5 seconds before you sends the first byte which means the connection cannot really consider established before that. It would make sense if Chrome tries to wait for confirmation of the connection before it tries open more to the same endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code like so:

```dart
void handle(HttpRequest request) async {
  print('A');
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  print('B');
  request.response.write('Hello');
  print('C');
  request.response.close();
}
```

2 tabs open in chrome, sending requests. One would expect to see `A-A-B-C-B-C` in console but in fact it's not so: `A-B-C-A-B-C`. @julemand101 pointed out, it has something to do with how Chrome handles connections/caches... Something under the hood. If you disable the cache in dev-tools, you get the result you expect. So it's unrelated to how Dart works and in fact a browser-related oddity.